# how to display a record in laravel with time interval?

Tags: sql, laravel

In laravel i need to display a record with time interval. I mean that only created past 24 hours before. How can do it by where clause. i have column with time and date in database and i need to display past 24 hours records only.

Comment: Provide your sql query / what you tried so far?

Comment: Provided he knows sql queries.

Comment: $data=DB::table('cart')->where("condition")->get(); @NitinDhomse

Comment: i don't how to compare with current time and past 24 hrs

Answer (score 0):

The query like this should work for you,

```
SELECT * 
FROM cart
WHERE cart.your_date_time_column > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: This is simple sql query, you can convert this to laravel compatible format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` like this :

```
$data=DB::table('cart')
          ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subHours(24))
          ->get();
```

Comment: Is there any problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your time and date column is named `created_at`

```
$past_24hrs = Carbon\Carbon::now()
                   ->subHours(24)
                   ->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$carts = DB::table("cart")
    ->where("created_at", ">=", $past_24hrs)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
Model::whereDate('column', '>', $this->freshTimestamp()->subDay())->get()
```